# ArcGIS Pro Label Placement grayed out in Scene

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcscene

I'm using Scene in  ArcGIS Pro I don't understand why my Label Placement is grayed out even though I've selected my Feature Class in the Contents panel and the Maplex Label Engine is checked? I'm new to Pro and could be missing something obvious.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESRI responded to this question on GeoNet stating it's a bug.

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/202158-arcgis-pro-label-placement-grayed-out?start=0&tstart=0